How do I get Qt Designer to find and load Python plugins (on Linux with anaconda)?
I'm on Linux (openSUSE 15.5) with PyQt5 installed through anaconda. Qt Designer is part of the qt-main package and works well, but now I want to use some custom widgets from the Silx project using their Qt Designer plugins. As far as I can tell, the normal Qt Designer doesn't behave according to those instructions, and I need to find and install the PyQt5 version of the designer.
According to the documentation, it should be possible to point to the plugins with the PYQTDESIGNERPATH env variable. As far as I can tell from the output of strace, designer completely ignores PYQTDESIGNERPATH. It only searches [conda-env]/plugins/designer/ but linking or copying the python plugins there doesn't make them show up in "About Plugins", not even as broken. My best guess is that designer doesn't know or care about Python files or anything PyQt-related.
I have found several references to pyqt5-tools which might contain a different version of the designer with the ability to cope with Python plugins, but no such conda package exists. If I try to install pyqt5-tools with pip, it suggests to download the whole of Qt and install it on top of what I already have. I know from experience that installing Qt from pip will break Qt-based packages because pip installs binaries that aren't compatible with the rest of the system (at least on the versions of openSUSE I've used), so that doesn't seem lika a viable option.
Thus my question: Is there some way I can use Python plugins for designer together with PyQt5 installed with anaconda?

Giving the path is insufficient: you installed PyQt separately, but PyQt also normally installs a specific C++ plugin (responsible of making Designer "use" Python for PyQt plugins) in the Designer path, and I doubt that is done by installing through anaconda. The file is libpyqt5.so, but it has to be built against the same Qt Qt build that Designer actually uses, so, assuming that the anaconda install actually put that file somewhere, it's not guaranteed that it would be compatible. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that you should probably consider installing PyQt for the whole system.

Ah, thank you for that information. I see that there was a post about libpyqt5 missing in anaconda3 as far back as 2018. And apparently this has been a recurring problem: in 2019 and now since 2022.

That's the problem with using third party installations. My suggestion remains: install PyQt system wide, that should solve the issue at its root.
